# Strange errors and error changes

Tags: errors, hyperref, amsthm, thmtools

Typesetting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{thmtools,amsthm,hyperref}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definizione}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand\listtheoremname{Definizioni, Teoremi, Proposizioni, ecc.}
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={defi}]
\end{document}
```

yields:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./gungugungu4.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-patch.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/parseargs.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-autoref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/aliasctr.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/remreset.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-listof.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-restate.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(./gungugungu4.aux)

Package thmtools Warning: amsthm loaded after thmtools .


Package thmtools Warning: ntheorem loaded after thmtools .

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./gungugungu4.out) (./gungugungu4.out)

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

./gungugungu4.tex:9: Extra \else.
\@forloop ...lse #5\def #4{#2}\ifx #4\@nnil \else 
                                                  #5\@iforloop #3\@@ #4{#5}\...
l.9 \listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={defi}]
```

Loading `thmtools` *after* `amsthm` solves everything, and removing `hyperref` yields:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./gungugungu4.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmtools.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-patch.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/parseargs.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-autoref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/aliasctr.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/remreset.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-listof.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-restate.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(./gungugungu4.aux)

Package thmtools Warning: amsthm loaded after thmtools .


Package thmtools Warning: ntheorem loaded after thmtools .

./gungugungu4.tex:9: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.9 \listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={defi}]
```

So the questions are: what is that error:

```
./gungugungu4.tex:9: Extra \else.
\@forloop ...lse #5\def #4{#2}\ifx #4\@nnil \else 
                                                  #5\@iforloop #3\@@ #4{#5}\...
l.9 \listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={defi}]
```

and why does it vanish by listening to the warning and loading `amsthm` *before* `thmtools`? Why does removing `hyperref` change the error so radically? What is calling `ntheorem`?

Comment: The documentation of `thmtools` tells you that `amsthm` must be loaded before it. So do it. The error is different because `hyperref` gets confused since it sees both `amsthm` and `thmtools` loaded and it can't know `thmtools` has ignored `amsthm`.

Comment: @egreg -- but where does `ntheorem` come from?  is that perpetrated by `hyperref`???  (oh, dear!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm not sure why the warning is issued. In any case it's a spurious warning that doesn't show up when the correct order of packages is used.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The spurious warning is due to misplaced braces in `thmtools.sty`.

Comment: @egre -- thanks.  (maybe we can get that fixed before tex live 2014.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've added to the answer the changes to be made.

Comment: @egreg in what sense does `thmtools` "ignore" `amsthm`?

Comment: @MickG With your code, `thmtools` doesn't see `amsthm`, so it adjusts its macros assuming you won't use it, but it emits code that can check whether `amsthm` is loaded later, in order to issue the warning.

Comment: Fixed packages at [http://absatzen.de/thmtools-v66.tar.gz]/[http://absatzen.de/thmtools-v66-texmf.zip] and going to CTAN in a few moments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of `thmtools` tells you that `amsthm` (or `ntheorem`) should be loaded before `thmtools`, so that the package can adjust its macros. So the correct call is

```
\usepackage{amsmath,thmtools}
```

The presence of `hyperref` is irrelevant. However, the error changes because at loading time, `hyperref` sees that both `thmtools` and `amsthm` are loaded, so it does its work assuming everything was done properly, because it has no way to know you made a mistake in the loading order. Well, it could also check for the loading of `thm-amsthm`, but it doesn't.

The warning about `ntheorem` is spurious and it is independent of `hyperref`. It is caused by bad code in `thmtools`:

```
 49 \@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{%
 50   \RequirePackage{thm-amsthm}
 51 }{%
 52   \AtBeginDocument{%
 53   \@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{%
 54     \PackageWarningNoLine{thmtools}{%
 55       amsthm loaded after thmtools
 56     }{}%
 57   }}%
 58 }
 59 \@ifpackageloaded{ntheorem}{%
 60   \RequirePackage{thm-ntheorem}
 61 }{%
 62   \AtBeginDocument{%
 63   \@ifpackageloaded{ntheorem}{%
 64     \PackageWarningNoLine{thmtools}{%
 65       ntheorem loaded after thmtools
 66     }{}%
 67   }}%
 68 }
```

Let's analyze the code, which is executed at the end of `thmtools`:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{%
  \RequirePackage{thm-amsthm}
}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{%
    \PackageWarningNoLine{thmtools}{%
      amsthm loaded after thmtools
    }{}%
  }}%
}
```

If `amsthm` has not been loaded, the third argument to `\@ifpackageloaded` is executed, which is

```
  \AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{%
    \PackageWarningNoLine{thmtools}{%
      amsthm loaded after thmtools
    }{}%
  }}%
```

What's stored in `\@begindocumenthook` is then

```
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{%
    \PackageWarningNoLine{thmtools}{%
      amsthm loaded after thmtools
    }{}%
  }
```

which misses the third argument to `\@ifpackageloaded`. It should be

```
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{%
    \PackageWarningNoLine{thmtools}{%
      amsthm loaded after thmtools%
    }%
  }{}
```

So the third argument of `\@ifpackageloaded` turns out to be whatever token follows and this is certainly a bug to be fixed. The code above should become

```
 49 \@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{%
 50   \RequirePackage{thm-amsthm}
 51 }{%
 52   \AtBeginDocument{%
 53   \@ifpackageloaded{amsthm}{%
 54     \PackageWarningNoLine{thmtools}{%
 55       amsthm loaded after thmtools%
 56     }%
 57   }{}}%
 58 }
 59 \@ifpackageloaded{ntheorem}{%
 60   \RequirePackage{thm-ntheorem}
 61 }{%
 62   \AtBeginDocument{%
 63   \@ifpackageloaded{ntheorem}{%
 64     \PackageWarningNoLine{thmtools}{%
 65       ntheorem loaded after thmtools%
 66     }%
 67   }{}}%
 68 }
```

Comment: thanks for the diagnosis.  i reported to the author, link to this answer, and have received a reply that he will try to fix in time for tex live 2014.